# How to deploy MuleApp in Tomcat server?

Tags: maven, deployment, tomcat7, esb, mule

Hi can someone answer me how to deploy muleapp in tomcat?

I have packaged muleapp using Maven -mvn package war:war but before building  and packaging it with Maven I had to manually add WEB-INF folder in muleapp cause the structure of muleapp is deferent to webapp.

is there any better way how to transform muleapp to webapp structure?

thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

[Mule Application](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Application+Format) and [Web Archive (WAR)](http://java.boot.by/wcd-guide/ch02.html) are two different formats, and for this reason they are not interchangeable.

To create a web application that uses mule you should start from the [maven war archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-webapp.html) and then following the instruction available [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Embedding+Mule+in+a+Java+Application+or+Webapp) to configure your web.xml

Comment: Thank you I did it, but I was wondering is there any other option? some export  or some plugin... ? Cause for instance if I have many MuleApps that I have to deploy in tomcat its not so convenient to add manually web.xml file and to package them.